# Java Map String <ListString> looping

Tags: java, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to loop thu a map using the codes:

```
Map<String, List<String>> newMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Assign some default values on the Map

```
    for ( int m = 1; m < attribteList.size(); m = m+2) {
        String newName = newList.get(m);
        newMap.put(newName , newList);
    }
```

know I need to add values in the Map

```
for (another loop) {
    String value1 = anyvalue;
    String value2 = anyvalue;

    Iterator it = pmMap.entrySet().iterator();
    int cnt = 1;
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();

        if(value1.equalsIgnoreCase(pairs.getKey().toString())) {
            for (List<String> list : pmMap.values()) {
                int a = list.indexOf(list);
                if (a == cnt) {
                    list.add(value2);   
                }
            }
        }
    cnt++;
    }
```

Problem is my loop doesn't work. I need to add value2 from the Map  based from there position or value from the map

Like:
If Map String (15) is equal to value1 (15)
    Find the Map Liststring with the value of 15 and place value2 inside.

Output data should be like this:

```
MAP: 15=[value2, 0, 0, 0] 16=[value2, 0, 0, 0, 0]  17=[value2, 0, ,0 ,0]
```

Anyone knows how to loop or search for the position or correct list?

Comment: What is `pmMap` here?

Comment: What should this be? `int a = list.indexOf(list);` the index of a list inside them itself?

Comment: It seems that you are `put`ing _the same_ list into the map for each key... What is this code supposed to do at all? What is `list.indexOf(list)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I am guessing that this `List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();` should be inside the loop you are updating your `HashMap` otherwise as @tobias_k mentioned you are inserting the same value to every key. I guess you don't want that.

You can use `keySet()` to get the key of your `Map` and loop in it:

```
Set<String> set = pmMap.keySet();
for(String key : set) {
ArrayList<String> list = null;
if(value1.equals(key)) {
list = pmMap.get(key);
list.add(value2);
pmMap.put(key, list);
}
```

I haven't checked the code but you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are assigning the same list to all values in the map you need not loop through the entry set. You could just get the value and do a replace all like `Collections.replaceAll(list, value1, value2);`

```
List<String> list = pmMap.get(value1);
if(list != null){
    Collections.replaceAll(list, value1, value2);
}
```

A sample

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {     
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> pmMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(){{ add("15"); add("16"); add("17"); add("18");}};

        for (int m = 0; m < newList.size(); m++) {
            String newName = newList.get(m);
            pmMap.put(newName , newList);
        }

        System.out.println(pmMap);

        String value1 = "15";
        String value2 = "19";

        List<String> list = pmMap.get(value1);
        if(list != null){
            Collections.replaceAll(list, value1, value2);
        }

        System.out.println(pmMap);
    }
}
```